# Use one icon size in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I generate a lot of apps for clients. Nowadays there are a lot of different icon sizes (57, 72, 114, 144, 120, 152, 180) in addition to the 1024 sized icon that we upload to iTunesConnect.

In practice, though, I just design the large 1024-sized icon, then manually resize the icon to all of those other sizes and put them in an asset catalog.

That seems like pointless busy work. Is it possible to just give Xcode my 1024x1024 icon and let the tools autoresize it to a smaller version?

Comment: Have you found an answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Xcode will allow this. However you can try using a web based application for resizing your icons simply. Try [makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com/). I am sure there are others out there.

Comment: I'd still have to keep them organized and drag them into the right Asset Catalog slots (and not make any mistakes while doing so)...

Comment: @DanFabulich I don't believe Xcode supplies any sort of way to automatically add in your launch icons. But this should save you some time in creating multiple images and exporting them. It has been suggest by others that these types of things should be submitted to Apple in hopes they will adopt some sort of fix to reduce the amount of time spent on this.

Comment: I use Preview to shrink my icons.

Answer (score 2):

The macOS Terminal can really help you here.

If you wanted to resize an image named `myicon1024x1024.png` to an image of the same filetype, but 72x72, open Terminal, use the `cd` command to change directories to where your `myicon1024x1024.png` image is, then execute this command:

```
sips -z 72 72 myicon1024x1024.png --out myicon72x72.png
```

The "sips" command has a lot of other options, which can be googled or learned from its man page.

You can also make a bash script which could take the input of your file's name, then call sips once for each icon size you want to create. Of course, the output of this bash script ends up being the same as what you would get from makeappicon.com, so you'd still have to move the files into Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It makes me very sad to write it here but I use Unity for it :-) Yes, 3D engine! Just create empty project, switch platform to iOS, set one 1024 icon and let build the project. Then you can drag and drop pre-made AppIcon into you XCode.